# MVVM DESIGN PATTERN

Tags: wpf, mvvm, c#-4.0

Am very much new to this MVVM DESIGN PATTERN.Am doing a small project in this pattern

In my project i have a button,if i click on that button it will create a new button at run time and we can create any number of buttons there.

Creating mutliple buttons is working and now am trying to move that controls at runtime where ever we want in the same window only.

I implemented some methods and now  controls are moving with my mouse point as i want but now what is the problem is::

if one button is created it is moving fine when the second button is created

then it is coming attached to the first button now both the buttons are moving together and third and so on..

i cant able to understand whats happening over there?

Can Any one help me  plz ??

Thanks In Advance

i dont know how to post code over here 
if anyone give me your mail id then i wil send whole project to them

ThanQ Once Again

Comment: We'll be able to help better if you show us your code.

Comment: I don't think this problem has anything to do with MVVM. Try to find the code which is causing the problem and post that so that we can help you better.

Comment: i dont know how to post code over here
if anyone provide there mail id,i will send my whole source code to them

Thanks

Comment: Paste in the relevant sections under the code tags that are available.  Press the button, paste the code, done.

Comment: I am creating a lot of controls one by one of same type dynamically with in a single button click

Here controls are creating in a single vertical line and controls are creating like a single instance/control but i want to create every next control as a different control
i hope u can understand my problem and please help me
Thanks In Advance
Krishna

Comment: Now what happen is :: am using a canvas in mainwindow.xaml file like this

 <Canvas Background="White" Height="421" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,6,0,0" Name="grid" Width="516">
 <ContentControl Name="ButtonName"
            Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"
ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
             />
 </Canvas>

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in Laurent Bugnion's "Understanding the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern" session at MIX10 http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/EX14